# How to get file uploaded time in wso2 esb sequence

Tags: file, ftp, wso2

I am using WSO2 inbound endpoint to fetch a file from an FTP server. And I know how to get the file name back. Now my question is how to get the file uploaded time back (or the last modified time)?

This is the code to get the file name.

```
<property expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')" name="ftp.var.filename" 
    xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

I think there should be a similar code to get the timestamp of the file.

Answer (score 0):

With the following property, you will be able to get the last modified time of the file polled from the inbound endpoint.

```
`<property expression="get-property('transport', 'LAST_MODIFIED')" name="ftp.var.last.modified.time" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>`
```

Add this to the relevant sequence to further process and following is a sample sequence in which the file name and the last modified time is logged.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="fileSequence" onError="fault" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('transport', 'FILE_NAME')"
            name="ftp.var.filename" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <property
            expression="get-property('transport', 'LAST_MODIFIED')"
            name="ftp.var.last.modified.time" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Please check whether this meets your requirement and please refer [1] to further clarify this.

[1]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/transports/core/vfs/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/vfs/VFSTransportListener.java#L767